# Get meta box to keep selection after update

Tags: php, wordpress, select, meta-boxes

I'm building a meta box for one of my custom post types that has a selection option. I'm trying to make it so that when you make a selection and update the post, the option stays selected when the page reloads. I've found a few people on StackOverflow working on the same and I've followed those suggestions but haven't quite figured it out yet. If anyone has any suggestions, any help is appreciated.

```
<?php

function property_info_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box('property-info', 'Property', 'property_info_cb', 'properties', 'normal', 'high'); 
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'property_info_meta_box');

function property_info_cb($propertyInfo) { 

    $selectAgent = get_post_meta($propertyInfo->ID, 'select-agent-value', true);

    ?>

    <label for="select-agent-text">Select Agent</label> <br>
    <select multiple size="5" name="select-agent" id="select-agent">

        <option value="none">None</option>

            <?php

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'agents',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
                );

            $posts = new WP_Query($args);

            if ( $posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>

                <option value="<?php the_ID() ?>" <?php selected( $selectAgent, the_ID() ); ?>> <?php the_title(); ?> </option>

            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    </select>

<?php }

function add_property_info_fields ($propertyInfoId, $propertyInfo){
    if ($propertyInfo->post_type == 'properties') {

        if(isset($_POST['select-agent'])){
            update_post_meta($propertyInfoId, 'select-agent-value', $_POST['select-agent']);
        }

    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'add_property_info_fields', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shot in the dark here, but you are using `the_ID()` improperly. This function prints the ID to the screen. You are trying to return the ID for use as a function parameter. You should try something like:

`<?php selected( $selectedAgent, get_the_ID() ); ?>`

See [get_the_ID()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) vs [the_ID()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID)

Comment: That was it! You rock!